# Getting value in datagridview cell error

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I have a `datagridview` and it contain 5 rows, the column name are: XS,S,M,L, and XL.

And the flow is first The user will choose a brand(CHL and XRA), and if the user choose the XRA, the column names will be rename to -,1L,2L,3L,4L.

What the problem here is that every time I get the value from the cell that the column name is renamed, I'm getting this kind of error: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

This is my sample code for getting the value from the cell:

```
dvJOBranch.Rows(0).Cells.Item("M").Value.ToString
```

This code is perfectly working if do not rename the column, but if I rename the column, its having an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the index of the column does not change, you could access it by its **index** instead of its name:

```
dvJOBranch.Rows(0).Cells.Item(2).Value.ToString 'third column
```

---

Note that *Object reference not set to an instance of an object* means you have a `NullReferenceException`

The line of code above supposes that:

- `dvJOBranch.Rows(0)` **is not null**, otherwise access to `Cell` will throw a `NullReferenceException`
- `dvJOBranch.Rows(0).Cells.Item(2)` **is not null**, otherwise access to `Item(2).Value` will throw a `NullReferenceException`
- `dvJOBranch.Rows(0).Cells.Item(2).Value`  **is not null**, otherwise call of `.ToString()` method will throw a `NullReferenceException`

You need to make appropriate tests to handle null values.

```
If dvJOBranch.Rows(0).Cells.Item(2).Value IsNot Nothing Then
    (...)
End If
```

See also [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Ah ok sir, I get it now, I have set the value of my datagridview to null, Thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
If dvJOBranch.Rows(0).Cells.Item(2).Value IsNot Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(dvJOBranch.Rows(0).Cells.Item(2).Value.ToString)
(...)
End if
```

The most important here is the OrElse (in stead of OR), because otherwise the second part of the equasion still gives the NullReferenceException.